# Is there any opensource meta-circular CLR implementation?

Tags: c#, .net, clr, metacircular

Is there any open source meta-circular implementation of .Net CLR? I know MONO is not entirely written in C# so I was looking for some sort of open source project which implements .Net CLR entirely in C# (something like [Maxine](http://labs.oracle.com/projects/maxine) for JVM) to get better understanding of .Net CLR.

Comment: There's an inevitable bootstrapping problem here, unsolvable until the operating system becomes managed as well.  At which point there's not a lot of reason for having a CLR anymore.  Mono is written in C btw.  Notable is that Maxine requires GCC version 4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read about Shared Source CLI, code-named "Rotor"?

Some links:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_Source_Common_Language_Infrastructure

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4917

Also it is interesting the Roslyn project, which is a C# compiler written in C#:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2011/10/19/introducing-the-microsoft-roslyn-ctp.aspx